# Qt 5 - QSettings, не пишется ini-файл

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ini

Приветствую.
Есть код: сериализация настроек приложения, сделанных как QProperty, в ini файл(потому что мне сказали, что реестр - плохой стиль).

```
Settings = new QSettings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, QApplication::organizationName(), QApplication::applicationName());

QString path = Settings->fileName();
```

и чуть позже:

```
const QMetaObject *metaobject = metaObject();
int count = metaobject->propertyCount();
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
    QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
    const char *name = metaproperty.name();
    QVariant value = property(name);

    QString Key = QString(name);

    Settings->setValue(Key, value);
}
```

В переменной path путь к ini-файлу:

> path = C:/Users/ILIA/AppData/Roaming/HighwaySoftware/Vesta 2016.ini

От русских букв в путях я ушел давно. Файл не создаётся. Думал, нет прав на запись, запустил из-под Visual Studio 2013, запущенной от администратора - нет результата. Чтобы вы не думали, что файл я не нашёл, я его искал через Everything c запросом:

```
*vesta*.ini
```

где vesta - имя приложения, его нет. В чём дело? В реестр вся информация пишется(правда, не всегда, я это не поборол).

Comment: Выяснил,  в чём дело. Нужно убрать не показанный кусок кода: `  if (Key.compare("UndoQueueSize") == 0)
  {
   DebugBreak();
  }
Не показал, поскольку посчитал мусором. Почему DebugBreak может так влиять, непонятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные сохраняются при вызове метода `sync`, а также при вызове деструктора и по интервалу в event loop. Вы создаёте `QSettings` в куче и, вероятно, сразу завершаете приложение, не удаляя объект.

Дебаггер останавливает все потоки, поэтому если вы после записи настроек замораживаете приложение, то настройки не успевают сохраниться.

Comment: Спасибо. Я это понял через час после написания вопроса, стыдно было, что такую простую вещь не знал. Вопрос помог.